# Percentage weighting given two variables to equal a target

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a target of target = 11.82 with two variables

x = 9
y = 15

How do I find the percentage weighting that would blend x & y to equal my target? i.e. 55% of x and 45% of y - what function is most efficient way to calc a weighting to obtain my target?

Comment: There isn't one answer to your query. Setting up an equation `9x + 15y = 11.82` clearly makes a line. You need another equation to create a system of equations so to constrain your parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at it again, what I think you want is really two equations:

```
 9x + 15y = 11.82
 x + y = 1
```

Solving that system of equations is pretty fast on pen and paper (just do linear combination). Or you could use `sympy` to solve the system of linear equations:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve
>>> x, y = symbols('x, y')
>>> linsolve([x + y - 1, 9 * x + 15 * y - 11.82], (x, y))  # make 0 on right by subtraction
FiniteSet((0.53, 0.47))
```

We can confirm this by substitution:

```
>>> 9 * 0.53 + 15 * 0.47
11.82
```

Comment: Thanks! Have to do this for significant amount of iterations, this code works.