# Percentage weighting of four variables to equal a target

Tags: model, statistics, percentage, weighting

I'm using excel and have got four variables for my model and would like to find the perecentage weighting blending all four variables together to equal the target.

The target is 1.15

a = 1.48 b = 2.15 c = 0.85 d = 1.62

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont know how much better I can explain the problem, I found a very similar question here for what I want to do here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69441137/percentage-weighting-given-two-variables-to-equal-a-target except instead of two variables I want to find out how to get the correct percentage weighting by blending 4 variables together to get the target number